# Edit method in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following class , its using Entity Frameworks to operate its tasks

**Repository Class**

```
public class LibraryRepository
{
    LibraryContext context = new LibraryContext();

    public void EditBook(Book book)
    {
        context.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

so I'm trying to use this **EditBook** method in my Web API

**Web API Controller Class**

```
public class BooksWebAPIController : ApiController
{
        private LibraryRepository db = new LibraryRepository();

        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutBook(int id, Book book)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != book.Book_Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.EditBook(book);   

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
}
```

I'm trying use above Web API `EditBook` URL in MVC project(as my client layer)
So I have created a client class in MVC project's `Model` folder like below

**LibraryClient Class**

```
public class LibraryClient
{
    private string BOOK_URL = "http://localhost:13793/api/Books";

    public bool Edit(Book book)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BOOK_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("Books/" + book.Book_Id, book).Result;

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Then in MVC Project's Controller Folder I have created following class and controllers to interact with front end

**BooksController Class**

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        LibraryClient lc = new LibraryClient();
        Book book = new Book();
        book = lc.GetBook(id);

        return View("Edit", book);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Book book)
    {
        LibraryClient pc = new LibraryClient();
        pc.Edit(book);
        return RedirectToAction("BookswithAuthers", "BookWithAuther");
    }
 }
```

But here this is compiling without any errors, when I select a book to edit its fetching correct book , but once I'm doing change of it and hit save its **not saving updated details** , whats wrong in my approach.

The methods `View`,`Create` and `Delete` created like this approach working fine. only issue is this `Edit` method

Comment: @jimpaine actually I'm infant to this Web API technology , still learning phase , can you suggest  what can I do here

Comment: Are you calling `context.SaveChanges()` anywhere? If not, call it after `context.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @Developer No , I'm not should I ?

Comment: Thats how you "commit" changes in entity framework. But Im wondering how your other methods were working without `context.SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: @Kez have you got your routes you are using for your WebAPI project. I would also expect the method to be called Put not PutBook or use the HttpPut attribute on the method.

Comment: @Developer okay Actually I created above repository class using 'auto generate scaffolding' seems that why I missed

Comment: Btw, Im assuming that you were able to hit that edit method successfully...

Comment: @Developer Oops that's successful why don't put as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling `context.SaveChanges()` anywhere? If not, call it after `context.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` .